# Javascript: Setting an img element's .src to a gif is also restarting the gif of every other img whos src was also that gif. how do i avoid this?

Tags: javascript, image, google-chrome-extension, event-handling, gif

so i'm making a chrome extension that involves changing an images gif src when a user hovers over it, like so:

```
El.onmouseenter = ()=>{
            El.src = chrome.runtime.getURL('gifTwo.gif')
}
El.onmouseleave = ()=>{
            El.src = chrome.runtime.getURL('gifOne.gif')
}
```

GifOne and Two are local files in the extension. the problem is that i have multiple img elements whose src is also gifTwo.gif. when i hover over the element it changes the gif to gifTwo, as expected, however it also restarts the gif of every other img element whos src is also gifTwo. And when the users mouse leaves the image, it changes to gifOne, again as expected, but it then restarts the gif every other image element whose src is also gifOne

**Any idea how to avoid this so that setting the src of one img element does not affect the gifs of other img elements with the same src?**

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple way to do this: Duplicate the GIFs, and have each image use its own

```
<img name="im1" src="...">
<img name="im2" src="...">


El.onmouseenter = ()=>{
            El.src = chrome.runtime.getURL('gifTwo' + this.getAttribute("name").substring(2) + '.gif')
}
El.onmouseleave = ()=>{
            El.src = chrome.runtime.getURL('gifOne' + this.getAttribute("name").substring(2) + '.gif')
}
```

Or you could spend days looking for a more elegant solution.

-- edit --

Also, I prefer to load all images and hiding (`display:hidden`) the alternate ones rather than changing the image src field. That way you can just change the display css style property rather than needing to load a new image. That's my 2 cents

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, however the number of gifs is programmatically generated. could be 2 could be 200, and there are 30 types of gifs. would be impractical to have so many gifs saved in the extension i think. Is there another way to achieve something similar without physically copying 3000 gifs?

Comment: @DanielGoldberg What are you doing here? It sounds like you are trying to save the world with computer generated GIFs... I don't understand. GIF is an archaic technology that (from what I've read) only hobbyists care about anymore. Where is the value in this?

Comment: lmao. I have a chrome extension that adds cats to pages so it looks like the cat is sitting/laying down ontop of the image. The default gif is of the the cat just layin there, tail wagin eyes blinking. Hovering over the cat switches the gif to a gif of that same cat but doing an action.  The user can add more cats to tbe page as they wish. i suppose i can have 4 copies of each gif, that could be fine enough